# .htaccess mod_rewrite working ONLY with HTML, not with my PHP files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, multiviews

I've just finished setting up my first app on localhost - and the .htaccess working incredibly fine. I just uploaded the files to Google Cloud LAMP Server, set up the database & got everything working -- however, for some reason the PHP files are not being located (?) which is strange because it's working in localhost just fine, and HTML files seem to be rewrited just fine as well!
Here's the error log in apache:

```
Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/html/index (None could be negotiated).
```

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

What is strange is that it's rewriting HTML with no problem but PHP files will throw this:

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

I tried pretty much everything:

- Changed /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
- Changed /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
- Made sure that 'a2enmod rewrite' is enabled

Still, getting

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: I assume you are requesting a URL of the form `example.com/index`?

Comment: Yes, the index being a PHP file.

Comment: If I attempt to go to an HTML file, it rewrites with ease!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If looks as if `MultiViews` is enabled, but `.php` files are not a permitted extension. `MultiViews` needs to be disabled for your mod_rewrite rules to be processed successfully. To disable MultiViews, add the following to the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

MultiViews is disabled by default, however, it is explicitly enabled (in the server config) on some distros.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
> ```

The first *condition* that checks that the request does not map to a directory is entirely redundant.

The *condition* that checks whether the corresponding `.php` (or `.html`) file exists is not necessarily checking that the same "file" you are rewriting to. If, for instance, you requested `/foo/bar` and `foo.php` happened to exist then you will get a rewrite-loop (500 Internal Server Error). To resolve this issue, it should be rewritten like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

The `NC` flag was superfluous, as was the *anchors* surrounding the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Comment: I'm attempting to do this:
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Options -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

However, still getting 'Not Found'. It's kind of stressing me out, probably I'm doing it wrong

Comment: @duro What is the document root? Is there any more restrictive `<Directory>` containers (perhaps in a `<VirtualHost>` block). Try adding some "nonsense" to the top of the `.htaccess` file - do you get an error? If not, then it looks like `.htaccess` files are not enabled.

Comment: .htaccess is enabled & it rewrites HTML files with no issue! This is out of my knowledge & can't find anything in Google for some reason. The closest I've been to seeing a solution was what you recommended with disabling MultiViews. I've added that line 'Options -MultiViews' to etc/apache2/apache2.conf & /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf, however with no success.

Comment: `Options -MultiViews` can be added to the top of the `.htaccess` file itself.

Comment: Are you still getting the same "Negotiation" error in the error log? `MultiViews` is part of mod_negotiation and is associated with _content negotiation_.

Comment: Wow! That fixed it.
If anyone has this same issue, just add `Options -MultiViews` at the top of your .htaccess

Comment: @duro So, wherever you were adding it in the server config was not right place (something else was overriding it). `.htaccess` will override the server config in this case. (I've updated my answer to state where this should be added.) "`<Directory /var/www/>`" - If you are requesting `example.com/index` (as confirmed in comments above) then it would seem your `DocumentRoot` is set as `/var/www/html`, in which case you should have a `<Directory>` container that reflects this.